# Is it necessary to create nested jSON objects before using it?

Tags: javascript, json

I think I've seen how to create a JSON object without first preparing it. This is how i prepare it:

```
obj = {
  0:{
    type:{}
  },
  1:{},
  2:{}
};
```

Now I think I can insert a value like: `obj.0.type = "type0";` But I'd like to create it while using it: `obj['0']['type'] = "Type0";`.

Is it possible, or do I need to prepare it? I'd like to create it "on the fly"!

**EDIT**

I'd like to create JS object "On the fly".

```
var obj = {};
obj.test = "test"; //One "layer" works fine.
obj.test.test = "test" //Two "layers" do not work... why?
```

Comment: You can create an object whenever you want.

Comment: why not try it?

Comment: Also, as you seem to be just starting out, [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Nina : I did try it.. but i can't get it to work.. thats why i'm asking this question... i have in my mind i have done it before...

Comment: it looks more like you need an array, with countable rows.

Comment: @NinaScholz Maby i do... I'm searching the DOM for inputs and saving the values into a object...to send to php with ajax..

Comment: basically you need to create the parent object first, if not exist. then create the property you want with the value.

Comment: But why does it work with single layer. But not second? `var obj = {}; obj.test = "test"; WORKS fine.. no preparing.. But: obj.test.test = "test"; don't work. How can i create "on the fly" nested objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj = {
  0:{
    type:{}
  },
  1:{},
  2:{}
};
```

> Now i think i can insert value like: obj.0.type = "type0";

I guess you mean "assign" a value, not "insert". Anyway, no, you can't, at least not this way, because `obj.0` is invalid syntax.

> But I'd like to create it while using it: obj['0']['type'] = "Type0";

That's fine. But you need to understand you are **overwriting** the existing value of `obj[0][type]`, which is an empty object (`{}`), with the string `Type0`. To put it another way, there is no requirement to provide an initialized value for a property such as `type` in order to assign to it. So the following would have worked equally well:

```
obj = {
  0:{},
  1:{},
  2:{}
};
```

Now let's consider your second case:

```
var obj = {};
obj.test = "test"; //One "layer" works fine.
obj.test.test = "test" //Two "layers" do not work... why?
```

Think closely about what is happening. You are creating an empty `obj`. You can assign to any property on that object, without initializing that property. That is why the assignment to `obj.test` works. Then in your second assignment, you are attempting to set the `test` property of `obj.test`, which you just set to the string `"test"`. Actually, this will work--because strings are objects that you can set properties on. But that's probably not what you want to do. You probably mean to say the previous, string value of `obj.test` is to be replaced by an object with its own property `"test"`. To do that, you could either say

```
obj.test = { test: "test" };
```

Or

```
obj.test = {};
obj.test.test = "test";
```

Comment: Thank you. Very well explained!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a plain object in JavaScript and you need to define any internal attribute before using it.

So if you want to set to `"Type0"` an attribute `type`, inside an attribute `0` of an object `obj`, you **cannot** simply:

```js
obj['0']['type'] = "Type0";
```

You get a "reference error". You need to initialize the object before using it:

```js
var obj = {
  0: {
    type: ""
  }
};

obj['0']['type'] = "Type0";

console.log(obj['0']['type']);
```

Comment: So it is not possible to create a object on the fly? Just by typing something like: `obj['0']['type'] = "Type0";`

Comment: No, you cannot. You need to initialize the object before using its internal attributes.

Comment: You are misusing the term "attribute".

Comment: @torazaburo what do you mean with "misusing"?

Comment: JavaScript objects do not have "attributes". They have "properties".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @torazaburo. I was using a more generic object oriented terminology. In object oriented paradigm an object has "attributes" and "methods".

Comment: In the JS world this is likely to be confusing, because "attributes" has the specific meaning of attributes on DOM elements (which in their shadow existence as JS objects can also have properties, which are entirely distinct from attributes, which are defined by HTML5).

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own function that takes `key` as string and `value` and creates and returns nested object. I used `.` as separator for object keys.

```js
function create(key, value) {
  var obj = {};
  var ar = key.split('.');

  ar.reduce(function(a, b, i) {
    return (i != (ar.length - 1)) ? a[b] = {} : a[b] = value
  }, obj)

  return obj;
}

console.log(create('0.type', 'type0'))
console.log(create('lorem.ipsum.123', 'someValue'))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary to create nested objects before using it?

**Yes** it is, at least the parent object must exist.

Example:

```
var object = {};

// need to assign object[0]['prop'] = 42;
```

create the first property with default

```
object[0] = object[0] || {};
```

then assign value

```
object[0]['prop'] = 42;
```

```js
var object = {};

object[0] = object[0] || {};
object[0]['prop'] = 42;

console.log(object);
```

Create object with property names as array

```js
function setValue(object, keys, value) {
    var last = keys.pop();
    keys.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || {};
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var object = {};

setValue(object, [0, 'prop'], 42);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: All "parents" must be created? even nested parents? Or is it enough to declare the first parent? `var obj = {};`

Comment: all parents need to be created first. you could use an array with all properties and iterate through.